# mysql convert a string from select to an IN condition

Tags: mysql, select

I have problem to make the syntax right. I want to do something like this:

```
   SELECT colum1 FROM table WHERE id=37 OR id IN (???SELECT friend_id_str FROM table where id=37 ???)
```

table_data:

```
           id        friend_id_str     
           37          1-9-12
```

I'd like to do it in one query to reach the same result as the following:

```
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=37 OR id IN (1,9,12)
```

What string function do I need to make the syntax right ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you're leveraging the benefits of using a relational DB.  You might make it easier for yourself with a many-to-many relation table.

That aside, have you looked at mysql's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function?

It'd work off the cuff if you had comma delimited friend_ids, but will still work with a simple `REPLACE()`.

```
SELECT colum1 FROM table WHERE id=37 OR FIND_IN_SET(37, REPLACE(friend_id_str, '-', ',') );
```

My only comment on this would be that it would be horribly inefficient, and I'd investigate an alternative if this is a production query.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a function that can transform a dash-delimited string into a dataset.

MySQL has a function FIND_IN_SET() to rescue bad table designs like yours, but it only supports finding a substring in a list delimited by commas, not dashes.

You could use a regular expression:

```
WHERE friend_id_str REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', id, '[[:>:]]')
```

That's not your full query, but I'm not going to write that for you. It's up to you to understand that how that expression works and adapt it to solve you problem.

You really should store the data in a normalized fashion. SQL was meant to treat each column as an irreducible scalar, not a list.

See also my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mysql you can use the REPLACE function. Try a simple select on the data like so:

```
SELECT REPLACE(friend_id_str, '-', ',') from table where id = 37;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you need.  This should handle any number of id's in the friend_id_str.  You just need three conditions so you catch it at the first position or last position properly.

```
WHERE friend_id_str like CONCAT(id, '-', '%') or
      friend_id_str like CONCAT('%', '-', id, '-', '%') or
      friend_id_str like CONCAT('%', '-', id)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Barlow's answer could be simplify like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT('-',friend_id_str,'-') like CONCAT('%-',id, '-%')
```

But I think you want:

```
select t1.*
  from table t1
exists ( select 1 from  table t2
          where  CONCAT('-',t2.friend_id_str,'-') like CONCAT('%-',t1.id, '-%') 
       )
```